# ComboBox (two-way) binding to object property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, combobox

In the database, table `TblPerson` has a `CHAR(1)` field called `Gender` with a check constraint on possible values null, 'M' and 'F'

I'm trying to display (and two-way bind) the (EF mapped to type `string`) `TblPerson.Gender` property inside a `ComboBox`, but I don't seem to be get it to work.

I bind my other controls (`TextBox`es) to the same `TblPerson` object without issues. Have set an `ItemsSource` according to the check constraint:

```
comboBoxGender.ItemsSource = new char[] { '\0', 'M', 'F' };
```

But then I fail to grasp the link between the `ItemsSource` and the binding of the object property. 
I'm not even trying to show 'male' or 'female' and link that to 'M' and 'F', so I don't think I need a converter (or do I?)

So what do I do with those (in)famous three `ComboBox` properties I need to set to make this work?
Been at this for some time, haven't made the *click* yet. Yes, I've read Microsofts [How to: Use SelectedValue, SelectedValuePath, and SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788714.aspx).

Comment: Is TblPerson.Gender a string? If it is your ItemsSource is a different type which is why it is not working.

Comment: @RichardE It was right in front of me but you pointed me to it. Well done! If you like, you can turn this into an answer and I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: No problem. I have added an answer so that it can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TblPerson.Gender and your ItemsSource items need to be of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, forget the "Tbl" naming. Entities are not tables. Entities are Entities.

Second, don't manipulate UI elements' properties in procedural code.

Thid, just use `SelectedItem` and you're good to go.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource={Binding SomeList} SelectedItem={Binding Person.Gender}/>
```

Comment: the Tbl naming is just what the generated classes are called because the tables are called like that. And it doesn't work. The `ItemsSource` does of course, but the `SelectedItem` doesn't.